# Converting String Object to Bytes and vice-versa using packer/unpacker Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to convert a string object to bytes and Vice-versa.

Is it possible using Ruby Packer/Unpacker?

I am unable to find the format specifier to use

```
*pack_object = "Test".pack('**x**')*      where x is format specifier
*unpacked_object = pack_object.unpack('**x**')*   , this should result in "Test" string
```

Comment: @cremno unable to unpack it

Comment: There's no `String#pack`, it's `Array#pack` and `String#unpack`

Comment: Please include the desired (intermediate) output

Comment: @Stefan can you explain me with some example Array#pack and String#unpack, The output which i need is the same strung which i packed.

Comment: `"Test".split('').pack` should do the trick.

Comment: @user1747819 that sounds like a XY problem. What are you trying to do? Why do you have to convert a string to bytes?

Answer (score 0):

`String` has a [`bytes`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-bytes) method that returns an array of integers:

```
'Type'.bytes
#=> [84, 121, 112, 101]
```

The equivalent [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-unpack) directive is `C*`: (as already [noted by cremno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539726/converting-string-object-to-bytes-and-vice-versa-using-packer-unpacker-ruby#comment51038761_31539726))

```
'Type'.unpack('C*')
#=> [84, 121, 112, 101]
```

Or the other way round:

```
[84, 121, 112, 101].pack('C*')
#=> "Type"
```

Note that [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-pack) returns a string in binary encoding.

Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539726/converting-string-object-to-bytes-and-vice-versa-using-packer-unpacker-ruby#comment51039077_31539726):

> The output which i need is the same strung which i packed

`pack` and `unpack` are counterparts, so you can use all kind of directives:

```
'Type'.unpack('b*')
#=> ["00101010100111100000111010100110"]

['00101010100111100000111010100110'].pack('b*')
#=> 'Type'
```